# Why does the induced electric field vary radially in a cylindrically symmetrical region where a time varying magnetic field is present?

Tags: electromagnetism

Ou high-school professor told us that a time varying magnetic field in a cylindrical region produces a sort of circular electric field which is Non conservative in nature, because Electric field varies radially, however, I fail to understand why that is the case.

Comment: [Faraday's law](http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m5/faraday.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the region outside a cylindrical tube of magnetic flux that varies in time, $\Phi(t)$. Faraday's law tells you the closed line integral of the E-field is (minus) the rate of change of magnetic flux enclosed. The line integral is the E-field (which will circulate around the tube in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction) multiplied by $2\pi R$.
$$\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l} = 2\pi R E_\phi  = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\ .$$
Thus, rearranging we have an E-field that falls as $R^{-1}$.

Why is this non-conservative? Well, because the closed line integral around the tube is non-zero.

If you want to consider the E-field within the flux tube then you need to specify how the B-field varies with $R$. If it were uniform then the enclosed flux on the right hand side of Faraday's law varies as $R^2$ and the induced E-field varies as $R$. In any case you cannot make the right hand zero if the enclosed flux varies with time, so the E-field will always be non-conservative.